# Javascript Rotate two wheels of fortune

Tags: javascript, html

Beste,

Today I have made a rotate image program with javascript.

HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="http://static.kuikr.com/images/quikr_logo_f3.png" >   
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Js:

```
var deg = 2; // starting
var rotation_diff = 30;

var rotation;

function start()

{
    rotation=1;    
    myFunction();
}

function stop()
{
    rotation=0;    
}

function myFunction() 
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");

img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.transform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.msTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
img.style.OTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";

    if(rotation==1) {



       setTimeout("myFunction()",1000);   } 
deg = deg + rotation_diff;
}
```

You see I have made a start and stop button, but I want this with a wheel of fortune. When it stops by a number I hope the javascript can alert the number.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1):

You could work out the degrees where your numbers on the wheel of fortune are, then use those.
e.g (pseudocode)

```
if rotation is greater than 0 and less than 90 then score = 50
if rotation is greater than 90 and less than 180 ect.
```